# Translations using Qt Linguist?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, translation, ubuntu-9.10

I am working on Ubuntu 9.10 aka Karmic Kola and latest version of gcc, Qt 4.6.2. I have installed the french fonts and hindi fonts for ubuntu. I changed the language and Keyboard layout accordingly so that I could type in the abovementioned languages. It worked fine. I then made a sample application and added appropriate translations in Hindi and French. The linguist tool worked fine then. I was able to type in Hindi in Linguist. This was around a week back.

Today I was making a different application with Hindi translations, with the steps that I did earlier using Qt Linguist. But now when I type in Hindi in Qt Linguist it gives only one character(for any keypress) which is like "=" with more space between the two horizontal bars in "equal to" sign. In the .ts file generated by lrelease the translations are displayed perfectly but on execution again characters in the form of squares appear as the translated text. I have tried umpteen times, even changing the codecrtr in .pro file but to no effect.

Can somebody point out why Qt Linguist is interpreting hindi characters as "=" but when typed in other applications like openoffice writer and browsers its perfect hindi fonts? I have torn my hair the whole day on this seemingly annoying problem. Didn't try for french though :).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head many times on this problem, I decided to try translations on a newer version of Qt and 
VOILA it did the trick. Probably there is a bug in Qt translations module in the version I was using. Notified Qt guys about the same. Hope others will find this information valuable.

Cheers!!!